# Как подстроить барьеры игры под любое разрешение?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Я делаю игру в стиле Air Hockey под Android.
Мне нужно, чтобы игра была под все разрешения экранов, но я не знаю, можно ли подстроить игровые объекты (например барьер) под все эти разрешения. Если можно - подскажите как это сделать, буду очень признателен!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: не делай игры на канвасе. Канвас должен использоваться по-назначению - для меню. Для игры он использоваться не должен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте узел Canvas и поместите в него то, что должно подстраиваться под разрешения.
Так же, добавьте всем узлам компонент RectTransform и настройте так, как вам нужно.